# OpenSSH disable ControlMaster for given hostname

Tags: ssh, mac-osx

I am using `OpenSSH_5.9p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011` with Mac OS X Snow Leopard. I have `ControlMaster` feature configured to maintain persistent connections. My `~/.ssh/config` have the following:

```
Host *
  ControlPath /ms/%r@%h:%p
  ControlMaster auto
  ControlPersist 4h

Host *.unfuddle.com
  ControlMaster no
```

However, from what I see - even when I am trying to use SSH for unfuddle.com hosts, master connection get always created:

```
[andrey-mbp ~]$ ssh -v git@droolit.unfuddle.com
OpenSSH_5.9p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/akhkharu/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/akhkharu/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: /Users/akhkharu/.ssh/config line 6: Applying options for *.unfuddle.com
debug1: Reading configuration data /usr/local/Cellar/openssh/5.9p1/etc/ssh_config
debug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master
debug1: Control socket "/ms/git@droolit.unfuddle.com:22" does not exist
debug1: Connecting to droolit.unfuddle.com [174.129.5.196] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/akhkharu/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/akhkharu/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/akhkharu/.ssh/id_dsa type 2
debug1: identity file /Users/akhkharu/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/akhkharu/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/akhkharu/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.8
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.8 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA a6:74:33:36:95:31:6e:a6:d7:71:87:b8:3c:38:e2:60
debug1: Host 'droolit.unfuddle.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/akhkharu/.ssh/known_hosts:390
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/akhkharu/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 277
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to droolit.unfuddle.com ([174.129.5.196]:22).
debug1: setting up multiplex master socket
debug1: channel 0: new [/ms/git@droolit.unfuddle.com:22]
debug1: control_persist_detach: backgrounding master process
debug1: forking to background
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: multiplexing control connection
debug1: channel 1: new [mux-control]
debug1: channel 2: new [client-session]
debug1: Remote: Forced command.
debug1: Remote: Port forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: X11 forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Agent forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Pty allocation disabled.
debug1: Remote: Forced command.
debug1: Remote: Port forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: X11 forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Agent forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Pty allocation disabled.
debug1: mux_client_request_session: master session id: 2
PTY allocation request failed
Need SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 2 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 2 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug1: channel 2: free: client-session, nchannels 3
debug1: channel 1: free: mux-control, nchannels 2
Shared connection to droolit.unfuddle.com closed.
```

```
[andrey-mbp ~]$ ll /ms/
total 0
srw-------  1 akhkharu  admin     0B Jul 17 11:55 git@droolit.unfuddle.com:22
```

Thanks,
Andrey.

Answer (score 27):

Your `*` host stanza is catching it. Put more specific host stanzas earlier.

Comment: Thanks, but that would not work for me. I need ControlMaster enabled for all hosts, but not for unfuddle.com. I can not list all hosts I use in config file. What seems to be working is placing the rule for unfuddle.com at the very beginning.

Comment: You mean... when you put the more specific host stanza earlier?

Comment: Yeah, it's strange, but it works.

Comment: I had been searching the manpages for ages, but it's a strange priority thing!

Comment: I'm afraid I'll wonder until my dying day if Andrey ever caught on to the fact that this answer is correct, and that the comment he agreed with points that out.

Comment: This answer might be improved by explaining *why* it works: ssh takes the first variable assignment it sees and ignores the rest. Thus more specific patterns go first in the file, where they will override latter assignments.

Answer (score 19):

As described in the answer to [my similar question on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/859661/how-can-i-force-ssh-to-ignore-the-identityfile-listed-in-host-for-one-specif), you can use the "bang" syntax to exclude specific hosts from the original `Host *` stanza, like this:

```
Host * !*.unfuddle.com
    ControlPath /ms/%r@%h:%p
    ControlMaster auto
    ControlPersist 4h
```

In my situation, I found that the order of the `Host` sections when using a `Host *` seemed to be irrelevant, but the above method always works.

Answer (score 11):

For me it works when I additionally set `ControlPath` to `none` within the `host` stanza.

You can try:

```
Host *.unfuddle.com   
    ControlMaster no
    ControlPath none
```

Then no control session will be generated.

Comment: In my case I had to do this plus put the `Host *` section at the end of the file and it worked.