# Issues with ssh and Ansible

Tags: ssh, ansible

When running an ansible task (with a `script` action), I'm getting this error message:

```
stderr: OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u2, OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master
debug1: mux_client_request_session: master session id: 2
Shared connection to 10.0.2.222 closed.
```

Now, there are a bunch of tasks targeting the same host before this one, and they all work fine.I know it's the client, because the client is Debian; the thing being provisioned is Centos.

When I tried to look up this error message, I discovered (to my chagrin) that what I got is usually the first part of some longer message for some other problem. I tried adding

```
Host 10.0.2.222
  ControlMaster no
```

to the beginning of my `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` because of [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/408416/openssh-disable-controlmaster-for-given-hostname) out of pure desperation, but it didn't work and I genuinely don't know what could have gone wrong; I don't know enough about how SSH works to even figure out what the most likely culprit would be.

Comment: Try SSHing directly to `10.0.2.222` with the key file and username you've got Ansible configured with. If it fails, turn on verbose output with `-v`.

Comment: @ceejayoz It doesn't fail. That's the issue; The keys are configured fine, I can ssh into root with no problems. it's only failing about 10 tasks in.

Comment: Try configuring `ControlMaster no` in your `~/.ssh/config` instead of the global one, perhaps?

Comment: @ceejayoz Nope. On the bright side, it's definitely applying the rules.

Comment: To me this looks like the rule is doing `ssh -v` to the client *on* the client, or something like that. Without you showing the playbook it impossible to say for sure.

Comment: Found out what it was when I ran the playbook with `-vvv`. Apparently, ansible was overriding the options in its command-line invocations of SSH. I'll answer this later today with my fix, but this certainly wasn't intuitive behavior on ansible's part. Nothing to do with my specific playbook; just stupid ansible nonsense assuming it knows better than my /etc configuration files.

Comment: check /home on the target machine - I got this error when /home was 100%

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This fixed the problem mentioned in the question (problems still exist with the ssh connection, but that's for another question).

By default, ansible adds some options which override `ssh_config` options. Specifically, it adds:

```
-o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o ControlPath="/home/devel/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r"
```

Figured that out by using `-vvv` with `ansible-playbook`.

You can fix / override those options by specifying `ssh_args` in the `[ssh_connection]` section of your `.ansible.cfg` as specified [here](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_configuration.html#ssh-args). Also worth noting is that, counter to what you might infer from the name, changing `ssh_args` doesn't actually change all of the args. Ansible also passes `-C -tt -v -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o ConnectTimeout=10` and other options (e.g. `-o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=root`), some of which are simply immutable defaults, and some of which depend on variables you've specified in the playbook.

Comment: Right, but which of the args in particular did you override to fix the problem?

Comment: The first step is to set `ssh_args` to `-o ControlMaster=no` to disable re-using SSH connections (aka [connection multiplexing](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Multiplexing)).  If that stops the failures, you could see whether your client or server openssh version is at fault -  see [this bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1242682) .  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39382868/992887) for similar issue solved by turning off ControlMaster.   Once you have reliable SSH, you can think about updating openssh to fix with ControlMaster turned on.

Comment: (a bit late in responding... but yeah when you asked what args I changed I couldn't tell you b/c it'd been a year since I had this problem. You're right though, @brk3 . It's a shortcoming of this answer. :P )